# How to crop the image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-clipping

I want to do the same thing as asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754618/how-to-crop-an-image-using-rectangale-overlay-and-touch-on-iphone) question.
In my App i want to crop the image like we do image cropping in FaceBook can any one guide me with the link of good tutorial or with any sample code. The Link which i have provided will completely describe my requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create new image with any properties. Here is my function, witch do that. you just need to use your own parameters of new image. In my case, image is not cropped, I just making some effect, moving pixels from there original place to another. But if you initialize new image with another height and width, you can just copy from any range of pixels of old image you need, to new one:

```
-(UIImage *)Color:(UIImage *)img
{
    int R;
    float m_width = img.size.width;
    float m_height = img.size.height;
    if (m_width>m_height) R = m_height*0.9;
    else R = m_width*0.9;
    int m_wint = (int)m_width;      //later,  we will need this parameters in float and int. you may just use "(int)" and "(float)" before variables later, and do not implement another ones
    int m_hint = (int)m_height;

    CGRect imageRect;
    //cheking image orientation. we will work with image pixel-by-pixel, so we need to make top side at the top.
    if(img.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationUp 
       || img.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationDown) 
    {
        imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, m_wint, m_hint); 
    }
    else 
    {
        imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, m_hint, m_wint); 
    }
    uint32_t *rgbImage = (uint32_t *) malloc(m_wint * m_hint * sizeof(uint32_t));
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgbImage, m_wint, m_hint, 8, m_wint *sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace,   kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, m_hint);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    switch (img.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI / 2);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -m_wint);            
        }break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, - M_PI / 2);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -m_hint, 0);            
        }break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        {
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, m_wint, m_hint);
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, img.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    //here is new image. you can change m_wint and m_hint as you whant
    uint8_t *result = (uint8_t *) calloc(m_wint * m_hint * sizeof(uint32_t), 1);
    for(int y = 0; y < m_hint; y++) //new m_hint here
    {
        float fy=y;
        double yy =    (m_height*(  asinf(m_height/(2*R))-asin(((m_height/2)-fy)/R)   )) /
        (2*asin(m_height/(2*R))); // (xx, yy) - coordinates of pixel of OLD image
        for(int x =  0; x < m_wint; x++) //new m_wint here
        {
            float fx=x;
            double xx =    (m_width*(  asin(m_width/(2*R))-asin(((m_width/2)-fx)/R)   )) /
            (2*asin(m_width/(2*R)));
            uint32_t rgbPixel=rgbImage[(int)yy * m_wint + (int)xx];
            int intRedSource = (rgbPixel>>24)&255;
            int intGreenSource = (rgbPixel>>16)&255;
            int intBlueSource = (rgbPixel>>8)&255;
            result[(y * (int)m_wint + x) * 4] = 0;
            result[(y * (int)m_wint + x) * 4 + 1] = intBlueSource;
            result[(y * (int)m_wint + x) * 4 + 2] = intGreenSource;
            result[(y * (int)m_wint + x) * 4 + 3] = intRedSource;

        }
    }

    free(rgbImage);

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(result, m_wint, m_hint, 8, m_wint * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace,   kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast  ); //new m_wint and m_hint as well


    CGImageRef image1 = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    UIImage *resultUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image1];
    CGImageRelease(image1);


    @try {
        free(result);
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"proc. Exception: %@", e);
    }

    return resultUIImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks SentineL for your response but i thing you didn't get me question i want to crop my image which i am doing with this lines of code `CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);
 CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(ImageREF.CGImage, cropRect);` but this cropping is hard coded i want the user to adjust the Rect for the image link shown in this [link](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/8930/customcropbox.jpg)

Comment: so... you just whant to make user interface, to choose rect to crop image? This is easy: just implement touches whatch on there moves. 4 blak bars with alpha 0.7 will mute area wich will be croped. You can handle 2 touches: according there coordinates, and knowing the they are at different sides of diagonal of ractangle, you will easy calculate sizes of 4 dark bars. just change tham on every move. or, with single touch: you will need 4 spaces (that blue circle). track touches and there moves to move tham

Comment: Thanks SentineL for you response and the way u guide me :)

Answer (score 3):

CGRect rectImage = CGRectMake(p1.x,p1.y, p2.x - p1.x, p4.y - p1.y);

```
//Create bitmap image from original image data,
//using rectangle to specify desired crop area

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageForCropping CGImage], rectImage); 
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(p1.x, p1.y,p2.x-p1.x p4.y-p1.y)];
imageView1.image = croppedImage;
[self.view addSubview:imageView1];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Comment: here imageForcropping is image which you want to crop..And cropped image which portion you want to crop..

Comment: any idea how to make this work when image rotates (ie when taken from iphone camera)?